# Filter options which exists in another array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two arrays, *countries* and *selectedCountries*.

A user can add a *country* from *countries* to *selectedCountries*.

Now, I only want to display the *countries* the user **did not** select already (the ones in selectedCountries) - however I cannot figure how to achieve this.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <select 
        ng-model="selectedCountry"
        ng-options="country.name for country in countries"></select>
    <button ng-click="addCountry(selectedCountry)">Add country</button>

    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="country in selectedCountries">
            <td>{{ country.name }}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

And the current Javascript:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.countries = [
        { id: 1, name: 'Denmark' },
        { id: 2, name: 'Sweden' },
        { id: 3, name: 'Norway' }
    ];

    $scope.selectedCountries = [];

    $scope.addCountry = function(country) {
        $scope.selectedCountries.push(country);
    }
}
```

How can I filter the displayed *countries*?

Here's a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S9rV2/19/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a filter for it. Your HTML:

```
        ng-options="country.name for country in countries |notin:selectedCountries"
```

And your filter:

```
app.filter('notin',function(){
    return function(items,matchset) {
        return items.filter(function(item){
            return matchset.indexOf(item) < 0;
        });
    };
});
```

It will automatically keep them up to date. Updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/jxwbwjdq/1/

Comment: It should be noted that this is an O(N^2) operation that will run every time that filter is applied. I would say it's not the most efficient approach available.

Comment: Is there a more efficient approach? Since `matchset` and `items` will change with every click, it will have to run again.

Comment: [My answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27420715/1945651) has two solutions in which one uses an O(N) operation when the button is clicked (and doesn't use a filter), and the other uses a filter with an O(N) running time and adds an O(1) operation to the button click event.

Comment: True, assuming you can afford to modify the original items. Unless it is a fairly large set, I would not worry too much.

Answer (score 1):

Controller:

```
   $scope.notinSelectedCountries=function(item)
                        {
                            if ($scope.selectedCountries.indexOf(item) < 0)
                            return true
                        }
```

View:

`ng-options="country.name for country in countries | filter :notinSelectedCountries"`

It will not change the array, just use filter

Answer (score 0):

Why not just remove countries from `$scope.countries` as they are selected:

```
$scope.addCountry = function(country) {
    $scope.selectedCountries.push(country);
    $scope.countries.splice($scope.countries.indexOf(country), 1);
}
```

Another efficient approach that makes use of filters is to mark the country objects as selected, and filter out the ones that are not selected:

```
$scope.addCountry = function (country) {
    $scope.selectedCountries.push(country);
    country.selected = true;
}

<select ng-model="selectedCountry" 
        ng-options="country.name for country in countries|filter:{selected:'!true'}">
</select>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YPqWNo

Answer (score 0):

Change this in your js:

```
$scope.addCountry = function(country) {
    $scope.selectedCountries.push(country);
    $scope.notselectedcountries = [];
    $scope.countries.map(function(item) {
       if($scope.selectedCountries.indexOf(item) < 0)
           $scope.notselectedcountries.push(item);
    })
}
```

and this in your html:

```
<table ng-if="notselectedcountries.length > 0" border="1">
```

Comment: No need to change the `ng-if` - what if they choose them all?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep `countries` intact, you can bind the select to a function instead of a list which filters out the `selectedCountries` from `countries`:

In your controller add

```
$scope.unselectedCountries = function() {
    return $scope.countries.filter(function(c) {
        return $scope.selectedCountries.indexOf(c) == -1;
    });
};
```

Then

```
<select 
    ng-init="selectedCountry = countries[0]"
    ng-model="selectedCountry"
    ng-options="country.name for country in unselectedCountries()">
</select>
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/S9rV2/21/)

Comment: This is somewhat what I was looking for. However, when removing a country from *selectedCountries*, it does not reappear. http://jsfiddle.net/S9rV2/22/

Comment: Sorry my fault in the fiddle, you should't remove from `countries` in `addCountry` - http://jsfiddle.net/S9rV2/24/